# MongoDB geoNear query returns wrong distance

Tags: javascript, mongodb, geolocation, mongoskin

I am getting wrong distance using mongodb geonear query. What I have done till now.

1. Saved the lat-long as
   `"Coordinates" : {
       "Longitude" : 174.811937,
       "Latitude" : -36.880177
   }`
2. Created 2d Index on Coordinates field of collection
3. distance returned is `"distance": 253.33004896638525`

I also tried 2dsphere index but result is same. Please let me know if anything that i am missing

```
db.collection('RestaurentMaster').aggregate([{
    $geoNear : {
        near : [174.780599, -36.855702],
        distanceMultiplier : 6371,
        distanceField : "distance",
        spherical : false,
        limit : 10,
        query : {...}
    }
}])
```